# Failed to install npm

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-cordova, taco

I updated to TACO 10 & VS 2015 2. I am getting the following error due to a long path.

```
1>  Installing npm 2.14.9. This could take a few minutes...
1>  Failed: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
```

Is there any way to tell VS to use the globally installed npm. I tried installing [.NET Web Development and Tools Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2015/03/19/customize-external-web-tools-in-visual-studio-2015/) and c[hanging the path orders on the External Web Tools options](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2015/03/19/customize-external-web-tools-in-visual-studio-2015/).

I also tried unchecking the use sandbox node but VS still tries to install npm.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check if this link helps:[Build errors caused by long path and file names](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tips-and-workarounds-general-readme/#build-errors-caused-by-long-path-and-file-names).

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't like the way `npm` would do the nested dependency trees in npm v1.x & v2.x, eventually they will throw this error. The nested dependency trees will create very long path names and will hit a cap in windows.

You should instead use npm v3.x, npm went to a [flat dependency structure](https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3) with v3.x and this issue will go away.

Comment: I have v3.x installed globally but VS Taco tries to use 2.14.9. The error hapens while installing npm.